# Piwik: Get graph of unique visitors in custom date range using ImageGraph API

Tags: matomo

I only just started using piwik but am already stuck.

I want to get a graph showing the unique visitors of a **custom** date range (from February to April), so a count for each day. Just as it's displayed in Piwik under "Visitors => Overview". But somehow that doesn't seem possible with the ImageGraph API.

What I'm trying to do (using the ImageGraph API):
I want to display a graph showing the number of unique visitors per day in a certain date range.
Below I want to display a graph showing all goal conversions per day for the same date range.

It's supposed to show the relation between the two values since it's highly relevant if an increase in conversion is accompanied by an increase in unique visitors.

It would be great if both sparklines were in the same graph but I don't think that's possible.

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

For daily visits you can generate the graphic by calling the next URL :

```
    $this->baseSite. 
    'index.php?module=API&graphType=evolution&width=800&height=200&method=ImageGraph.get&idSite=' .
    $this->siteId . '**&period=day**'. **'&date=' .
    $this->startDate->format('Y-m-d') . ',' .
    $this->endDate->format('Y-m-d')** .                     
    '&apiModule=VisitsSummary&apiAction=get&token_auth='.
    $this->apiKey
```